# Please help me software brick (all data erase) my iPhone 5c in-hand

Tags: ios, itunes, software-update, filesystem, firmware

My screen is broken, but I can force DFU, which I did.

In iTunes, I get "Cannot update software."

The to restore I Download 10.3.3 firmware, error 14 cannot update.

Any workaround that you can think of for erasing the data on this device?

Comment: Apple has stopped signing iOS 10.3.3, you cannot update to it anymore.

Comment: Thank you kindly. And this is the only firmware that works with 5c right?

Comment: It's the latest one, all the others aren't being signed as well. :/

Answer (score 2):

No easy workarounds if iTunes won't restore / erase an iPhone in normal mode, let alone when you have it in DFU mode. Apple Configurator might be worth a try, but it uses the same library / underlying erase code the last time I checked. Same with Xcode.

I suppose the only workaround is to disassemble it and destroy / sanitize the data by jumping some of the pins to take control of the storage. The getting it open might be easy for most skilled people - the jumping the pins would need specific technical tools and training as would getting a controller to erase systematically the data.

- Physical destruction would be the alternative to software erase
- repairing the phone to functionality also would be an alternative